# How to accelerate template display with multiple heavy ModelChoiceFields?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Through a `django` form, I want to display quite a big number of `ModelChoiceFields`. These fields are identical (showing the same list of people). But, the thing is I have a lot of entry for those fields. **The more fields I have, the more time it takes to load the template**, even if I thought the queryset (identical for every fields) would be evaluated only once.

---

### Hypothesis and issue

My hypothesis is that the queryset is evaluated as many times as the number of required fields. If that is what's happening, **I have no idea how to optimize the way my fields are being initialised**.

---

### What I want and what I don't

- I am not looking for a live search solution (ajax kinda),
- number of entries is acceptable when there is only one field (I've got a search field to filter people),
- the issue is really happening when I have more and more fields to display, even if the queryset is the same for each one.

---

### My code

```py
from django import forms
from . import exceptions
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User

class MyForm(forms.Form):

    # defining a dict here, and using it in __init__ to define multiple fields within a loop
    # NOTE : 'pc{i}' will be the name of one of the fields. queryset for each is defined in __init__
    nb_pcs = 16
    pcs_dict = {}
    for i in range(1, nb_pcs + 1):
        pcs_dict.update({
            f'pc{i}': forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, required=False)
        })

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        # getting user through kwargs
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        if not self.user: raise exceptions.DontKnowWhoFillsForm_Error()
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # defining the queryset that will be used for each field 'pc{i}'
        user_queryset = User.objects\
            .filter(groups__name='RegularAccount')\
            .order_by('last_name')

        # defining the fields themselves
        for key, value in self.pcs_dict.items():
            self.fields[key] = value 
            self.fields[key].queryset = user_queryset
```

---

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Where is your error or problem? Large amounts of options in MCF will put some load to the db. You already posted the answer to your question: You could use some ajax-typeahead thing. There are plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: Actually, if I only have one MCF, it will take an OK amount of time. But, if I've got 20 MCF with the same queryset, then it will take ~ 20 more time to render. And I think there must be a way to reduce that time, because of the identical queryset. I don't understand why it takes so much time to render, if my queryset is evaluated only once!

Comment: Its the same within djangos admin. Watch your computers (clients) cpu load: The browser is taking time to render the dropdown I think.

Answer (score 0):

First use [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to find out what's slowing down your page - it could be the queryset (which you've already solved) but it's likely template rendering.

You could render the `ModelChoiceField` options on the backend in your view then pass it to the template as context using `render_to_string()`.

First create a template for your options.

```
# user_choice_field_options.html
{% for obj in queryset %}
  <option value="{{ obj.id }}">{{ obj.first_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Then in your view you would render the options and pass it as extra context so it can be used as a template variable.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.views.generic import FormView

class MyView(FormView):
    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    form_class = MyForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        users = (
            User.objects
            .filter(groups__name='RegularAccount')
            .order_by('last_name')
        )
        context['user_options'] = render_to_string(
            'user_choice_field_options.html',
            context={'queryset': users},
            request=self.request,
        )
        return context
```

Then in `my_template.html` you could render the widget manually as many times as you'd like.

```
<select name="field_1" required="" id="id_field_1">
  <option value="">---------</option>
  {{ user_options|safe }}
</select>
```

To go even further you could add in [template fragment caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Reading this looks good, I will definitly give it a try and tell you if it helped, thanks!